# Alternative to UrlHelper.Content in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm looking for an alternative in ASP.NET 2.0 to : ASP.NET 3.5's System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.toabsolute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is about as close as you'll get.